# Which of the modern transistors could be a substitute for 2N709?

Tags: transistors, counter, repair, high-frequency

I need to replace the damaged Q1 transistor, but I don't have a 2N709. I was thinking about 2N2222 because of the similar case type. However, this transistor differs in frequency. In this follower circuit, would the lower frequency make a difference? The diagram is part of the HP5245L counter circuit.

[image]

Comment: Electrically, it should be easy to match or exceed every parameter. My best tip would be to try to not limit yourself to an antiquated capsule type if you can’t find any matches to it. Make a PCB with though-holes to match the pinout and solder an SMD to the other side, or find a not so antiquated THT and bend the legs to match. Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: @winny No I did not simulate it - do you mena LTSpice? I would like to keep it vintage look, so I'm looking for TO-18 replacement eventually. Do you think 2N2222 would work?

Comment: Yes, LTspice or similar. This does however assume you have models for both. Unless the circuit somehow relies on the super low input capacitance of the 2N750, I don’t see any reason why it shouldn’t.